# How to access "Security" tab in properties within default Parallels Windows 8 setup?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, parallels

First of all, I'd like to stipulate that I've tried two methods already (the normal Windows way) to enable the "Security" tab:

1. **Gpedit**
2. **Regedit**

I won't detail the process any further than that since there's no need.

Even after making the necessary changes in both areas, I still have no Security tab. To make sure, I restarted explorer.exe and then I restarted the machine. The settings have persisted, but still, nothing.

I suspect it's something to do with Parallels and how it's set things up--possibly the user it's given me.

Does anyone know how to enable this within Parallels with Windows version 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem, in case anyone happens to encounter the same thing...

**The issue**

As taken from [Microsoft's docs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-HK/windows7/Why-is-the-Security-tab-missing-from-my-file-and-folder-properties?1db1c580):

> The Security tab is also only available on drives that are formatted using the NTFS file system. If you are using the FAT or FAT32 file system, you will not see the Security tab. For more information on NTFS

So since it's Parallels via Mac, there are some areas in which one can store files that won't be formatted as NTFS, meaning permissions remains unavailable even if enabled. There's no need to use the solutions mentioned in my OP since by default the policy is not configured.

In order to use those controls, store them in `C:` within your VM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason for it was that my File path to the file in question was too long (inside quite some folders) + file names were different length and some worked and some did not (was trying to ADD files to VLC player, and some worked, some did give me an error message).

So after shortening some names of the folders, out of sudden the Security tab appeared back up and VLC out of sudden had no issues having files added to the play list...

Hope this helps... someone...